# matplotlib configuration file and style sheets

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can check the location of my matplotlib configdir via

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.get_configdir()
```

If I now place my `matplotlibrc` in `mpl.get_configdir()` I expect it to be loaded with the changes applied to plots if the following points to the desired `matplotlibrc`

```
mpl.matplotlib_fname()
```

However, it seems not all changes are applied.
Most notably font size changes are missing, while e.g. facecolor changes are applied.

If I load the `matplotlibrc` via

```
mpl.pyplot.style.use(mpl.matplotlib_fname())
```

Everything seems to work as expected.

What am I missing here?

It shouldn't matter, but I tested this in a jupyter notebook.
In addition, the `matplotlibrc` seems not to be reloaded after I change something.
Is there a way around it?

Comment: Once I had the similar issue that changes in ``matplotlibrc`` did not have any effect. I  resolved it by removing the cache directory. In my case it was ``~/.matplotlib``.

Comment: @MaximIvanov unfortunately this didn't solve the problem. Btw, one can see the cache dir via `mpl.get_cachedir()`.

Comment: Does it help if you run `mpl.rcParams.update(mpl.rcParamsDefault)` directly before the call to `mpl.style.use(style)`?

Comment: @Asmus, calling `mpl.rcParams.update(mpl.rcParamsDefault)` reverts the partial settings of my `matplotlibrc`. When I load my `matplotlibrc` via `mpl.style.use(matplotlibrc)` everything works as expected. However the problem is that when I load `matplotlib` it seems ignore settings in my `matplotlibrc` even though `mpl.matplotlib_fname()` mentioned that this is the current config file in use.